# AngularJS bootstrap dropdown navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I'm learning bootstrap and have a problem.

I made a dropdown on navigation bar. However, when I clicked on it, the dropdown wasn't collapsed. The `class="dropdown"` doesn't change to `class="dropdown open"` and the directive `"aria-expanded"` doesn't change from `"false"` to `"true"`. Only when I go to another page and then come back, the dropdown menu will work properly. I'm wondering why this is hapenning.

And I'm using two bootstrap libraries because I need boostrap 4 to use card deck container

index.html (with all updated files)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower-angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-ui-router@1.0.3/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

board.html

```
<div ui-view>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Today</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tomorrow</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dates</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#/home">August 1st</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/home">August 2nd</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <cards></cards>
</div>
```

Comment: are this page made also with angular cause i see an ui-view , also in the script i dont see the bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2.js    only for boottstrap 3

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention. I'm using angularJS to make the page. I included the script for bootstrap 4, but the browser (Chrome) showed more errors. That's why I deleted the script to keep me error free before posting. Is that a possible cause for this problem? Let me try putting that back and fix those errors

Comment: i made a plunkr and i dont see the issue you commente heres the link https://plnkr.co/edit/BT2cwrh60otS0NgNs1pn?p=preview

Comment: I just added bootstrap 4 script and its required tether.min.js. I still get same error
@JesusCarrasco I ran my code on plunk and see no error, too. I made sure I cleared cached and ran it in incognito mode every time I ran the program. don't know why it happens on my local machine.

Comment: Have you try on diferent browser, maybe a plugin causing the issue.

Comment: I tried it on firefox, but nothing's different. I haven't tried on IE though because I don't like that browser

Comment: can you replicate the code in some fiddle o plunkr because is difficult guessing :P cause i dont see nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to function correctly locally for me and in the included snippet. Maybe ensure that there aren't any caching issues in your test environment.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ui-view>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Today</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tomorrow</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dates</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#/home">August 1st</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/home">August 2nd</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <cards></cards>
</div>
```